# Doubts with stack pointer

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Conside a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c){
    char buffer1[5];
    char buffer2[10];
}

void main(){
        function(1,2,3);
}
```

compiling this with
    gcc test.c -m32 -g -o test -fno-stack-protector
and doing
    objdump -S test > test.dis

I get the following dump for the function "function"

```
void function(int a, int b, int c){
 80483ed:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483ee:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483f0:       83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
        char buffer1[5];
        char buffer2[10];
}
```

Consider another variant of the same program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c){
        char buffer1[7];
        char buffer2[10];
}

void main(){
        function(1,2,3);
}
```

on compiling and generating the dump with same commands i get:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c){
 80483ed:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483ee:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483f0:       83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
        char buffer1[7];
        char buffer2[10];
}
```

my question is what causes the stack pointer to be decremented by 16 in first case and 32 in second case while only 2 more bytes are required in 2nd case?

I am running 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 on Intel processor

Comment: Looks like stack alignment. ceil(log2(15)) == 4, and 2^4 == 16. ceil(log2(17)) == 5, and 2^5 == 32.

Comment: I don't understand what the mystery is. Isn't it obvious? It would really help to know what you expected or what you want explained.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think he's just wordering why there is 16 bytes more stack space used when actually only 2 bytes more are needed.

Comment: @MichaelWalz So then we have three possible readings of his question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html):

> `-mpreferred-stack-boundary`=*num*
>   Attempt to keep the stack boundary aligned to a 2 raised to *num* byte boundary. If `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` is not specified, **the default is** 4 (**16 bytes** or 128 bits), except when optimizing for code size (`-Os`), in which case the default is the minimum correct alignment (4 bytes for x86, and 8 bytes for x86-64).

So as space is allocated on the stack for the arrays, the stack is also being aligned on the default boundary of 16 bytes. In the first case you've got 15 bytes of data which is less than 16, so 16 bytes are allocated. In the second case you've got 17 bytes of data which is more than 16 but less than (the next multiple of 16) 32, so 32 bytes of space is allocated.

Comment: What importance does this alignment hold? I mean why does the compiler bother to do this alignment?

Comment: AFAIK GCC does it to be able to store SSE data on the stack, as some SSE instructions have alignment requirements.

Comment: @Siddhant,@Michael: It's not just SSE. Unaligned reads/writes are *SLOW* in x86. In ARM (and many other architectures), it's even worse: it'll crash the program (typically via a bus error).

Comment: In addition to efficiency, you will find that the calling conventions into the standard libraries on an OS will enforce this.